# Day difference between rows related to other row that is not NA

Tags: r, dataframe

Let I have such a data frame(df):

```
Date          x 
20.01.2016    34
21.01.2016    28
22.01.2016    NA
23.01.2016    NA
24.01.2016    56
25.01.2016    NA
26.01.2016    28
```

I want to add such a column(z) to this data frame

```
Date          x      z
20.01.2016    34     - 
21.01.2016    28     1 
22.01.2016    NA     NA     
23.01.2016    NA     NA
24.01.2016    56     3
25.01.2016    NA     NA
26.01.2016    28     2
```

where z shows the day difference between the related row's date and closest previous date (where x is not NA).

For example for the date 24.01.2016 the closest previous date is 21.01.2016 where x is not NA. So the day difference of these two dates is 3.

How can I do this using R?

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the data frame ordered by date?

Comment: Yes @Bob Jansen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cinsidering that your date variable is `as.Date`,(i.e. `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = '%d.%m.%Y')`) then,

```
df$z[!is.na(df$x)] <- c(NA, diff.difftime(df$Date[!is.na(df$x)]))

df
#        Date  x  z
#1 2016-01-20 34 NA
#2 2016-01-21 28  1
#3 2016-01-22 NA NA
#4 2016-01-23 NA NA
#5 2016-01-24 56  3
#6 2016-01-25 NA NA
#7 2016-01-26 28  2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Date := as.IDate(Date, "%d.%m.%Y")][!is.na(x), z := Date - shift(Date)]

df
#         Date  x  z
#1: 2016-01-20 34 NA
#2: 2016-01-21 28  1
#3: 2016-01-22 NA NA
#4: 2016-01-23 NA NA
#5: 2016-01-24 56  3
#6: 2016-01-25 NA NA
#7: 2016-01-26 28  2
```